# Access localhost through IP behind proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, localhost

I have apache server running on my machine. So when I type

```
localhost/test.html
```

on my browser's address bar, it correctly opens a test page which I have created. But when I try to open it by

```
<myIPAddress>/test.html
```

it doesn't open.
I am accessing the internet through proxy.
Moreover, when I access internet without proxy, it correctly opens test page.
Do I have to do some proxy setting in apache configuration or else ?

Comment: Are you accessing your public IP? Because then you'd have to set up port forwarding in your router, which is, depending on the model, more or less (usually less) reliably implemented by the manufacturer.

Comment: Yes, I am using public ip (which I got to know from whatismyip.com). Can I access that ?

Comment: As i said, you have to configure your router to forward requests to your PC. This is rather a question for SuperUser though.